# How to find which server is serving the request in Weblogic Cluster

Tags: weblogic, jndi, weblogic12c

Am Weblogic beginner.

I have created an application to test the JNDI load balancing. My application is deployed on Admin server that uses JNDI which is deployed on Cluster containing two servers(MS1, MS2). Know, my question is how can we know which server in the cluster is serving the request to client.

Thank you,
Vardhan

Comment: This looks like the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8792703/get-the-name-of-the-server-in-which-i-am-receiving-requests-to-my-app-on-weblogi

Comment: @better_use_mkstemp   String serverName = System.getProperty("weblogic.Name");      this is showing only deployed server name not the name of JNDI server.